# Easy fixes for Boolean Modifier Problems

Tags: modifiers

I had the Problem, that i hadnt an solid 3D printable object and needed help. A offline friend helped me then and i wanna share the solution with u, in case u need help and didnt get any.

1. When applying Booleanmodifier it helps to scale the piece times 1.1, when the errors are gone u can then convert it into a mesh. And then again scale it by 0.9090909090909 to get back to the original shape
2. u apply the remesh voxel modifier after u applied the boolean modifier and put it above the boolean modifier.

[image]
[image: this is how it is supposed to look like]

[image: u can see there, that it isn't solid]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Okay, next time i will do it like this ^^. I just wanted to fasten up the process so i could finish this project faster.

Comment: File link says no access.

Comment: fixed, the link should work for all people now